# Using C++ standard library in dll internally

Tags: c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I have read in many places that you should never use C++ standard library classes in the api of a shared library. Now what I am unsure about is whether it is safe to use a standard library class like std::vector in a dll privately, and only expose a pointer to the data.

I am trying to create a dll that will dynamically be loaded at runtime, does this change anything?

Also do I need to worry about how I will link the standard library to the dll? Is that consistent across platforms?

Comment: Do you have a link to a source that claims that this should not be done?

Comment: @t.niese if your DLL links to a different version of the library than the app does, really bad things can happen.

Comment: @MarkRansom sure, that's true. But that is not limited to the types of the std library but can happen with any library if the linked library versions don't match.

Comment: @t.niese true, but the standard library is both more likely to change and less likely to be suspected as a cause of problems.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes on windows ABI compatibility of the binaries created by different versions of compiler toolsets prior to 2015 did not exist. So libraries like boost, qt, opencv, … ship with different binary builds for all those toolchains. Since 2015 you have ABI compatibility. But again, that is neither a problem of shared libraries or std data types, but generally when linking happens and with any library. If you know what you do the std types are probably less a problem then other libraries, if you don't know what you do all of them are a problem.

Comment: No, linking the standard library to the dll is not consistent across all platforms.   It *may* be consistent across some platforms (e.g. with compatible ABIs, where that compatibility has been deliberately implemented) but will not be in general (e.g. between platforms with different ABIs).     That's equally true for any library, not just the standard library.

Comment: @t.niese ABI compatibility doesn't solve everything.  `std::vector` for example might have different members between two different versions of the standard library, so even though the function parameters will be passed the same the object implementations will be out of sync.

Comment: @MarkRansom when talking about ABI compatibility there are the compiler ABI (stuff like how function calls are translated to machine code, layout, alignment, …) and library ABI compatibility which is a combination out of library API and compiler ABI. If a library says that, certain versions are [library] ABI compatible then the members of their types match and have the same size and layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally considered bad practice to use non-POD data types across the DLL boundary.  Bad things happen when the calling module uses different versions/implementations of the data types that the DLL's public API uses (ie, when the calling module uses a different version of the same compiler/framework that the DLL uses).  Or, even when the calling module doesn't support the data types at all (ie, when the calling module is written in a completely different compiler/language than the DLL is written in).

When sharing DLLs, you should design the public API as though it were targeting the C language only, as that is the most portable option amongst various compilers/languages that support accessing DLLs.

However, the DLL can freely use whatever it wants internally for its private implementations.  Just don't expose those details publicly.

Comment: Even targeting C isn't quite enough.  If the app and DLL have their own copy of the runtime library, you'll get odd effects like having two heaps.  If you `malloc` from one heap and `free` to the other, good luck finding the bugs that ensue.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was referring just to data types, memory management across the DLL boundary is a whole other issue.

Comment: Wrap the C DLL with C++. Have that wrapper contain classes (or ex: a typedef of unique_ptrs that have a custom deleter, etc), instead of calling free on the app side, call the function in the C DLL that cleans up. Don't use anything inside that wrapper on the app side. It's a little extra work, but keep the DLL boundary at the perimeter of the app code, and make it robust. (Same advice holds for Rust, C#, etc.)